# Can I have a common Queue to queue up the requests received through function call?

Tags: java

I will be happy, if you can give me some suggestions to solve my problem.

I have to make a function call from one program to another program (separate package).  Now my question is, can i have a common Queue in the called program in which all the calling requests will be queued up ???? is it possible to maintain a queue??

Example.

```
package1:

public class Callingprogram
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        CalledProgram cp=new Calledprogram();
        cp.function(hashset);
    }

}


package2:
public class Calledprogram
{
    public void function(Hasheset hs)
    {
        here i am going to make use of the hashset sent by them
    }
}
```

now here by i repeat my question :can i make any queue in Calledprogram such that it keeps track of all the calls made by Callingprogram and serves one by one...if so can i have a sample code such that i can proceed further....

Thank you..

Comment: Why do you think you need a queue?  Does Calledprogram run a separate thread to process the queued requests?  If so, that's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).
It works for you!
Claudio